# c# : A connection with the server could not be established

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, azure-virtual-machine, azure-web-app-service

I know this question has been asked multiple times, but couldn't find anything matching exactly to my scenario.

I have 2 Web APIs , say WebAPI1 and WebAPI2. WebAPI1 is developed using .Netcore and is deployed in Azure. WebAPI2 is developed using .NET framework 4.6.1 and is deployed in a Azure VM using IIS.

Now I have to make a request from WebAPI1 to WebAPI2. I have made a call to WebAPI2 using httpclient.

After hosting, when trying to make a request, it is throwing following error:

> the connection with the server could not be established.

I have added ports 80 and 443 to the VM to the Inbound port rules. That didn't solve my problem. I'm guessing this might be a firewall issue. What things can I try to solve this?

### Edit

The IP address of my VM is like 10.x.x.x. In IIS , I have added a application in default website with name : `WebAPI2`. In the web API I have controller method name `GetData()`.

I have route prefix : `[RoutePrefix("api/App")]`. So the URL I'm using is `http://10.x.x.x/WebAPI2/api/App/GetData`.

Comment: Is your WebAPI1 deployed in Azure web app service?

Comment: @NancyXiong yes

Comment: If so, why do you use the private IP in your URL? It should be a public dns name or IP address when you request to your WebAPI2 on Azure VM from WebAPI1.

Comment: You could try to use public ip address or DNS name like `xxx.region.cloudapp.azure.com` associated to that VM in the URL ?

Comment: @NancyXiong what to do if we do not have public IP address for that VM. Our organization restricts us to create public IP for any Azure VMs.

Comment: just confirm from your comment `The URL which I have mentioned is returning data as expected when sending a request through postman` Do you do this with private IP In URL from postman in local Azure VM?

Comment: @NancyXiong I have done this my local machine. But my local machine and Azure VM are under my Organization's network.

Comment: So It seems this URL just works in a private network, the public Azure web app service could not find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you could not access the WebAPI2 on Azure VM from WebAPI1 in the Azure web app service with URL `http://10.x.x.x/WebAPI2/api/App/GetData` since public Azure web app service could not find the private IP in the URL.

In this case, you could enable [VNet integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet#enabling-vnet-integration) in Azure web App service. This gives your web app access to resources in your virtual network but doesn't grant private access to your web app from the virtual network. Also, these networks can then be connected to your on-premises networks using VPN technologies.

[image]

Moreover, If Azure web app set up their VNets, some [Networking Restrictions/Considerations](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#networking-restrictionsconsiderations) could be different in Azure web app sandbox.

> In particular, the restrictions on private and local
>   addresses are ignored if the target network interface belongs to the
>   app. Other VNet adapters on the same machine cannot be accessed, and
>   all other network limitations are still apply.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I will try this and get back to you.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have bound a domain to the iis website(WebAPI2) or directly use the IP of the VM with the specified port.

Comment: See the IP address of my VM is like 10.*.*.*. In IIS , i have added a application in default website with name : WebAPI2. in the web API I have controller method name GetData(). I have route prefix :  [RoutePrefix("api/App")]. So the URL i'm using is --> http://10.x.x.x/WebAPI2/api/App/GetData .

Comment: I have added the same info, in the question with better formatting. The URL which I have mentioned is returning data as expected when sending a request through postman.

Comment: Why'd you add "WebAPI2". I don't think its required when the application itself is mapped to an IP and are you missing an 'http://'?

Comment: Because there are some other web applications added in the default website. So I need mention the application name along with IP address. I have missed http:// in my comment. But I do have that in my URL.

Comment: Try using a port other than 80. This seems to be a firewall config issue as you already mentioned, if it works for other ports then you might need to configure the firewall for port 80 and likely 443 as well.

Comment: I have tried. It is not working for any port. And also I have added 80 and 443 in Inbound port rules